# Convert value of excel database to postgresql database

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, jsp

I have a jsp page with one browse button and one submit button.After selecting any excel file(.xlsx) when I click submit button, I want to store all the value of excel page to postgresql database.

Comment: if you are finding a jar which confirms a complete solution to that then i would say NO... you should use your own logical implementation to do so. @user3909042

Comment: I am not searching full solution .........but as i am new to java.....I am searching for starting help......

Comment: you should use `apache-poi` to read an excel file and then store it into a `database`...

`apache-poi` jars enables you read write any `excel` data Files. @user3909042

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and ready solution. You have to build implementation parsing .xlsx, handle data, and then insert into your database.

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) or [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for parsing Microsoft documents.

Working with database:

[JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)

Or you can use framework for simplify your job:

[Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Or you can use ORM, if you will work with many entities and frequent CRUD operations:

[Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html)